# Mono & ternary operator. Only assignment, call, increment

Tags: mono

I'm using Mono/.NET 4.5, MonoDevelop 5.7.0 and Mono 3.12.1 (tarball Fri Mar  6 18:53:33 GMT 2015) (64-bit), OpenSUSE 13.2.

The problem is, when I try to use ternary operator (?) like in this simple case:

```
using System;

namespace ternaryTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 1;
            int j = 2;
            i > j ? i = j : j = i;
        }
    }
}
```

I get

`/home/lucassith/ternaryTest/ternaryTest/Program.cs(19,19): Error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement (CS0201) (ternaryTest)`

I read that ternary operator is supported since mono 3.8.0.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ternary operator is an expression.

You can use it within statements such as assignments, return values, parameter values, etc.

This is one way of using it:

```
using System;

class X
{
   public static void Main ()
   {
     int i = 1;
     int j = 2;
     int m = (i > j ? j = i : i = j);
   }
}
```